# What is the opposite of Americanize?

Tags: terminology

If someone "corrects" your British spelling, they are said to be "Americanising" -
 or should that be "Americanizing"? ;) - your post. What is the opposite situation called (i.e. American --> British)? Anglicising? Britainising? Australianising?

I would automatically opt for "Anglicise", but that usually implies morphing a word from another language (most logically French or another European language) to make it "compatible" with English. I can't think of an example off the top of my head though.

Comment: Someone should make a case for _[arrogate](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/arrogate)_...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### "Britishize" and "Briticize" both are used, but neither seems extremely well established

There doesn't seem to be any verb meaning "convert to British English spelling" that is as common or well-established as *Americanize/ise*. Google search shows numerous examples of people using "Britishize/ise" and "Briticize/ise", although these words are mostly not recorded in dictionaries (something that many people attach some importance to, although dictionaries are not actually meant to be used as arbitrators of what is and isn't a word).

On the other hand, the apparently analogously formed nouns ***[British](http://www.onelook.com/?w=Britishism&ls=a)***ism and ***[Britic](http://www.onelook.com/?w=Briticism&ls=a)***ism, counterparts to *American**ism***, are common enough to have entries in many dictionaries.

And while neither of the verbs has an entry in the OED as of yet, that dictionary does record *Briticization/isation* which is quite similar.

I don't have any good data about how "Britishize" and "Briticize" compare to each other. The one that first came to my mind was "Briticize," but I don't know how typical that experience is.

### I can't think of any other plausible candidates

"Anglicize" seems far too ambiguous to me due to its use in reference to the English language in all its forms.

There aren't a huge number of synonyms for "Britain" or "British English", and I can't think of any that seems suitable as the base for a verb:

- "Commonwealth English" is a term that is sometimes used, but I don't see any comfortable way of turning it into a verb. Anyway, something like "Commonwealthize" would also be ambiguous since "Commonwealth" also refers to a generic type of political entity.
- There's the "United Kingdom" or "UK", but "UKize" sounds as bad to me as "Usonian" and other adjectives people have tried to coin based on US/USA to replace "American", and I expect it would have about as much success.
- There's "Albion", but that's mainly used in tongue-in-cheek references to "perfidious Albion," and I don't much like the sound of "Albionize" anyway.

Comment: +1 I suppose it shows the dominance of the US in modern culture. It's also interesting that the "-sh" becomes a "-c" (usually). Personally, I would use the "-c" because it sounds more correct.

Answer (score 4):

For converting a spelling to the UK standard, I believe you could use the word [***Anglify***](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/anglify). From Oxford Dictionaries:

> VERB
> *with object* To make English (or British) in character; to put into English form.

This definition isn't far off from the definition of *anglicise*, but I think anglicise is so dominant for converting foreign words to English that Anglify could be easily distinguished in the realm of language.

This definition is, incidentally, identical to the one in the *Oxford English Dictionary*; that resource is, unfortunately, behind a paywall<sup>1</sup>, but a couple of its attestations are particularly pertinent:

> 1922   *Times* 6 Dec. 15/5   Ex-Service men going out under official auspices..are bound to succeed so long as they realize that..they must Australianize themselves and not try to Anglify their fellows.
>
> 2003   *Daily Record* (Glasgow) (Nexis) 28 July 15   So why do Scots feel we have to Anglify our accent all the time?

("Anglify, v." *OED Online*. Oxford University Press, March 2017.)

The first of these suggests an appropriate term for converting to an Australian spelling, and the second shows that the term can be used to distinguish dialects within the anglophone world.

---

<sup>1</sup> If you don't have access to the OED, you might try checking with your local library; many have subscriptions to this fabulous resource, which members can access from home.

Answer (score 3):

### Englishise (also spelled *Englishize*)

> 1 To make English in manner or in language: ‘the Englishised Indian’ (Blackwood's Magazine, 1922). Source: *[Concise Oxford Companion to the English Language](http://www.oxfordreference.com/view/10.1093/acref/9780192800619.001.0001/acref-9780192800619-e-428)*

Ostensibly, to "make English"could also infer spelling e.g. The American English spelling *aluminum* would be Englishise to *aluminium* (British English).

### Englishing

*The action or process of "English"; an instance of this.*
 [Oxford *Living* Dictionaries](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/englishing)

Comment: I've upvoted this answer, but I agree that it would more likely be understood to mean "to translate into English".

Comment: What happened to *Anglicise"? This whole post is a bit ridiculous (not yours, I mean the whole thing) - trying to think of a way of explaining English (the language of England) as a variant of a variant. But I see the problem. I think it was Microsoft (in one of their versions of Windows), which allowed you to chose between "American English" and "International English". Since most non-American versions tend to follow the British spelling etc, that would seem as good an expression as any.

Answer (score 2):

The example you are giving is usually called simply *borrowing* or *calquing,* depending on how concepts get transferred from one language to another. All languages borrow from other languages, so it'd be more accurate to just use a more general term. Like if Swiss German-speakers borrowed a word from standard German and changed its meaning, you could say they borrowed it (plain and simple), or that they Helveticized it, which is like trying to sound cute.

Comment: You misinterpreted the question. The OP is asking about "Englishing" American *spellings*. There's no borrowing involved.

Comment: @Mari-LouA I think they were commenting on my inference of "Anglicise".

Comment: @DogLover but it's not very clear, is it? `you could say they borrowed it ... or ... Helveticized` which sounds like jlovegren is suggesting that as an answer.

Comment: @Mari-LouA I think jlovegren must be expanding on the concept of "borrowing". But I see what you're saying - it does look a bit like an answer to the original question.

Comment: I regret to say that I find this batch of comments somewhat irritating! Have you ever been irritated by someone who borrows a piece of your property and duly returns it in a soiled condition? I happen to think that this is the case here.

Comment: @Mari-LouA a question about spellings sounds pretty boring!